# Broken references in F# project

Tags: visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-2019

When I load a .NET Core F# project in Visual Studio Community 2019 I get the following:

[image: Visual Studio F# project with references listed individually with yellow icons]

The project is perfectly valid and builds fine with the `dotnet` command.

Does anybody know what's causing this?

Comment: That's a completely different issue.

Comment: Apologies - I'll delete my comment in that case. Is it worth including your dotnet / visual studio versions?

Answer (score 1):

If restarting Visual Studio doesn't fix this, you likely have assembly conflicts. To get more details, run `dotnet build -v d` to perform a detailed build. This will undoubtedly list your conflicts. Otherwise, the [output window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/output-window?view=vs-2019) in Visual Studio will reveal the problem as well.